# Making complex model without database Django

Tags: python, django

On `django 3`

When I need data without real database(like mysql), I can use `m.IntegerChoices`

This `CallType` never changes so `IntegerChoices` is suitable.

```
from django.db import models as m
class CallType(m.IntegerChoices):
    PULL = 1 
    PUSH = 2

class BaseCall(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 't_BaseCall'

    call_type = m.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        choices=CallType.choices, default=CallType.PULL)
```

Now I want to expand `CallType` more complex.

```
class CallType(m.IntegerChoices):
    PULL = {"number":1,"name":"pulling"}
    PUSH = {"number":2,"name":"pushing"}
```

What practice should I use?

I am afraid `IntegerChoices` is not suitable for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add labels to [Django enumeration types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#enumeration-types), pass tuples to each member where the first element is the value and second element is the custom label

```
class CallType(m.IntegerChoices):
    PULL = 1, "pulling"
    PUSH = 2, "pushing"
```

Comment: Thank you solving my problem for now. however I have another problem When I need more than second element. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71359124/call-missing-1-required-positional-argument-value-in-form